# Java regex to extract common elements of a string and remove leading commas

Tags: java, regex

I'm doing a practice problem on codeeval that asks about set intersection. The way the site
expects the input & output is deliberately convoluted to make it a bit more complicated I think.

The specific part of the problem is take two sets (arrays of Strings really, the exact problem is at http://codeeval.com/open_challenges/30/), find their intersection, print them in order, comma seperated. I've solved it using TreeSet, but it was a bit convoluted and overly complicated, and now I'm trying to get it a bit cleaner using regexes.

I found this -

```
String common = bothSets[0].replaceAll("[^" + bothSets[1] + "]", "");
```

In another question on stack overflow. It leaves leading commas in, which I tried to fix with

```
int subIndex = 0;
while(common.charAt(subIndex) == ',')
    subIndex++;

System.out.println(common.substring(subIndex, common.length()));
```

Which works except in edge cases like small string sizes or null string sizes, and then it exploded. I think it would be cleaner to just fix the regex and avoid that while loop altogether, but I don't know how to add "remove leading commas" to the above regex.

Finally, my original solution is here - http://pastebin.com/10NuBevB - am I right to be looking at alternatives like the regex approach, I'm not particularly happy with that pastebin code, even though it works and this doesn't yet.

Any direction appreciated.

Comment: Finished solution here - http://pastebin.com/kuXP5w4S

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `TreeSet`s and the `retainAll` method is probably the clearest approach to calculating the actual intersection.  You could do something clever with two regular expression matchers running in parallel over the two original strings (taking advantage of the fact that you know the input sets are already sorted) but that may be an optimization too far - keep it simple and clear unless you know (from profiling) that the code needs to be optimized.

My only comment is that your code to generate the output is rather convoluted, how about building the output up yourself rather than post-editing `toString`:

```
Iterator<String> iter = a.iterator();
if(iter.hasNext()) {
  // first entry with no comma
  System.out.print(iter.next());
}
while(iter.hasNext()) {
  // subsequent entries with a preceding comma
  System.out.print(",");
  System.out.print(iter.next());
}
System.out.println();
```

Comment: That answer is bang on, thank you. I knew there had to be a cleaner way to format the output!

Answer (score 1):

So as far as I understand your problem - you have got String like this:

```
[1, 2, 3,4]
```

and you want to make it look like this:

```
1,2,3,4
```

Try this regex - it matches all *[*, *]* and *spaces*:

```
String common = bothSets[0].replaceAll("(\\[|\\]| )", "");
```

Comment: No, I end up with a string (as in, in my problem) ,,,,,1,4, and need to remove the leading commas. The iterator solution above is the cleanest. 
Have another read of the question, I don't think you quite get it.

Answer (score 1):

A variant of the TreeSet version:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.TreeSet;

public class MyTest {

    public static List<String> getDuplicates(List<String> dups) {
        final List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
        Set<String> set = new TreeSet<String>() {
            public boolean add(String s) {
                if (contains(s)) {
                    result.add(s);
                }
                return super.add(s);
            }
        };
        for (String t : dups) {
            set.add(t);
        }
        return result;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String input = "7,8,9;8,9,10,11,12";
        String numbers = input.replace(';', ',');
        List<String> elements = Arrays.asList(numbers.split(","));

        System.out.println(getDuplicates(elements)); //[8, 9]

    }
}
```

I assume that a list doesn't contain duplicates.

Comment: I LIKE this answer, interesting way of doing it but it leaves me with the leading [ and trailing ] of the toString method, which puts me right back with having to hack at the output. Also, the question doesn't guarantee that the list won't contain duplicates so I can't assume that. 

I do like it though, some food for thought, I'll upvote as soon as I have the reputation to.